# self join providing wrong answers

Tags: mysql

Hypothetical data - **tbl1:**

| orderID | SupplierID | Status | Reason | Created At |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 |  | 1 |  | 22-01-2021 22:08 |
| 29 |  | 2 |  | 22-01-2021 22:10 |
| 29 | 265 | 3 |  | 23-01-2021 06:25 |
| 29 |  | 2 | sometext | 23-01-2021 12:25 |
| 29 | 1605 | 3 |  | 24-01-2021 10:21 |
| 29 | 1605 | 4 | anothertext | 24-01-2021 11:03 |
| 29 | 324 | 3 |  | 26-01-2021 06:43 |
| 29 |  | 2 | sometext | 26-01-2021 12:43 |
| 29 | 1564 | 3 |  | 26-01-2021 16:09 |

Desired result:

| orderID | SupplierID | Status | Reason | Created At |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 265 | 3 |  | 23-01-2021 06:25 |
| 29 | 324 | 3 |  | 26-01-2021 06:43 |

My query -

```
select distinct tbl1.orderID, tbl1.created_at, tbl2.supplierID 
from tblxyz as tbl1 left join tblxyz as tbl2
on tbl1.orderID = tbl2.orderID 
where tbl1.status=2 and tbl1.reason='sometext' and tbl2.status=3 and tbl1.created_at < (tbl2.created_at + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
group by tbl2.supplierID
```

I am unable to figure out where is my query wrong.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: The version is 8+

Comment: Describe the logic which produces such desired result.

Comment: Your query is nonsensical. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: supplier ids dont exist when status = 2 but they exist when the status = 3. I want to get the supplier ids (status =3) where the status = 2 and reason is sometext.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why don't you want 1605 or 1564? Given the order id is always 29, I don't understand how you can tell which status=2 records belong to which supplier.

Comment: @TomMelly order ids are way more. Just for the example, I posted 29. They range from 10-10000.

Comment: @Tangent that doesn't answer my question. Why, in the above example, did you not want 1605 or 1564? What makes them visibly different in the data you've provided from 265 and 324?

Your answer seems to be "because they don't have associated status=2 records, but those status=2 records don't identify which supplier they belong to.

Comment: @TomMelly because 265 and 324 are the supplier ids which succeed with status = 2 and reason = 'sometext' .

Comment: @Tangent but there are no supplier ids against the status=2 entries. How do you know which supplier they belong to?

Comment: @TomMelly many suppliers can be assigned to an orderId to get the ones where status is 2 and the reason is sometext we need to pick it up from the row above it where status has been 3.

Comment: @Tangent 'row above it' really has no meaning in this context, unless you are referring to the order returned by a particular 'order by' (which you haven't specified).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LAG` window function to get previous status and reason, then do your judgment.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tblxyz(
   orderID int,
  SupplierID INT,
  Status INT,
  Reason VARCHAR(50),
  CreatedAt DATETIME
  
);


INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,NULL,  1,'','2021-01-22 22:08');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,NULL,  2,'','2021-01-22 22:10');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,265  , 3,'','2021-01-23 06:25');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,NULL,  2,'sometext','2021-01-23 12:25');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,1605,  3,'','2021-01-24 10:21');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,1605,  4,'anothertext','2021-01-24 11:03');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,324  , 3,'','2021-01-26 06:43');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,NULL,  2,'sometext','2021-01-26 12:43');
INSERT INTO  tblxyz VALUES (29,1564,  3,'','2021-01-26 16:09');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.orderID,t1.SupplierID,t1.Status,t1.Reason,t1.PreviewCreatedAt
FROM (
  select *,
         LAG(Status) OVER(PARTITION  BY orderID ORDER BY CreatedAt) PreviewStatus,
         LAG(Reason) OVER(PARTITION  BY orderID ORDER BY CreatedAt) PreviewReason,
         LAG(CreatedAt) OVER(PARTITION  BY orderID ORDER BY CreatedAt) PreviewCreatedAt
  from tblxyz 
) t1
WHERE PreviewStatus = 2 AND Status = 3 AND PreviewReason='sometext';
```

| orderID | SupplierID | Status | Reason | PreviewCreatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 1605 | 3 |  | 2021-01-23 12:25:00 |
| 29 | 1564 | 3 |  | 2021-01-26 12:43:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kosXp8H1efwTpPrXo9E9KN/1)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need in this:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM tbl1 t1
JOIN tbl1 t2 USING (orderID)
WHERE t1.Status = 2
  AND t2.Status = 3
  AND t1.Reason = 'sometext'
  AND t2.Created_At BETWEEN t1.Created_At - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND t1.Created_At 
ORDER BY t1.Created_At;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=543d9150d1b23a01df01e0223f3fb3f2